Apply paint bucket tool to layer other than target layer
I have a series of "bubbles" that I'm trying to color in. Yes, really, the bucket tool is what I want to use for speed. Making a selection is not the right move here unless you know of a way to do it very quickly.
It looks like this:

Except there are thousands of these bubbles that I have to manually color. One way is to constantly resize the brush tool, but a better way is to just use the gradient -> paint bucket (g) tool and bubble in each circle.
The problem is, I don't want to recolor the original "bubble" layer itself, but a new, separate layer.
However, the paint bucket tool will only work on the selected layer. i.e if I create a new layer, I can't click one of these bubbles (in the new layer) and have it fill.
There must be a way to apply paint bucket fills to a new, (currently) blank layer.
Do I need to write an extension? I'm willing to do this but I suspect this is not a problem that someone else has faced.
Bonus points (or I guess just my gratitude expressed to the best of my ability) if you can answer the original question but also suggest a better or perhaps automated way of accomplishing this task.
Thank you in advance, graphic design stack exchangers!

What you're looking for is checking the option "All layers" in the top menu bar:

It works at least in 15 years old Photoshop as expected.

Try the same paint bucket tool options.
If you worked in a vector program (Illustrator, Inkscape etc...) you could select rings by the same stroke color and let them all have the same fill color -  For example fill 1000 yellow rings with 5 clicks. The curves are still there. Fill color, stroke width and stroke color are separate properties of the same closed shape.

Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I edited your response to highlight exact settings to accomplish this. Hopefully that is OK.
